# jsx snytax error using && operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
render() {
        const { show } = this.props;

        return (
            { show && 
                <div className="main">what's wrong?</main>
            }

        )   
    }
```

I got snytax error using above jsx, no clue why is this doesn't work.

Comment: What result did you intend?

Comment: @E.Sundin the logic is simple right? if show is true then show the main tag.

Comment: Remove the `{`,`}` inside the return statement

Answer (score 4):

The first error is because of the braces wrapping `show && <div>...`.

> `Unexpected token, expected ,`

Braces represent multiple things and which depends on the context that they're being used within. Placed after the `return` keyword, regardless of the parenthesis, they're being interpreted as an [Object literal/initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). The parser is expecting `show` to be a key followed by either a closing brace, comma, or a `:` and a value, and it instead finds `&&`.

```
return ({
    key1,
    key2: value2
});
```

Braces don't begin to represent JSX's inline code expressions until they're inside of an element. For example:

```
return (
    <div>{
        show && <div className="main">what's wrong?</main>
    }</div>
);
```

Without a wrapping element to distinguish them as a code expression instead of an object, they should be removed:

```
return (
    show && <div className="main">what's wrong?</main>
);
```

---

Once you've resolved that, a 2nd error will be raised:

> `Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <div>`

This is because the `<div>` is currently mismatched with `</main>`. Changing the latter to `</div>` will resolve it.

```
return (
    show && <div className="main">what's wrong?</div>
);
```

---

You can also use a good-ol' `if`:

```
if (show) return <div className="main">what's wrong?</div>;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is

```
render() {
  const { show } = this.props

  return (
   <div>
     {
        show && <div className="main">what's wrong? </div>
      }
   </div>
  )
}
```